# char[] vs char* in scanf C when writing memory

Tags: c, scanf

I'm  trying to use a `char*` data type to store a string from user, the code  compiles fine but it fails when executing the `scanf` instruction,
a fixed array `char[10]` works smoothly but I'd like to know how can I use a `char*` instead.

*bouclesCon.c*

```
#include "bouclesCon.h"
/... ... ...
void func_While(){
//char message[10] ="hey" ;//good
char*message="hey";//copiles but fails to execute
while(strcmp(message,"sortir")!=0){
    printf("vous avez ecrit %s\n",message);
    scanf("%s",message);
}
}
```

*main.c*

```
#include"bouclesCon.h"
int main()
{
  func_While();
  return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

As explained  by carveone and Igor , the problem was  related to the allocation of  enough  memory when  using  a char pointer(char*)  to write  a user input at runtime through scanf(), in constrast  an  array handles  the memory  differently.

**SOLUTION** working code :

```
`void func_While(){
    //char message[10] ="hey" ;//good
    char*message="hey";//copiles and  execute fine!!
    message=malloc(10);
    if(message==NULL){
        printf("error\n");
    }else{
        while(strcmp(message,"sortir")!=0){
            printf("vous avez ecrit %s\n",message);
            scanf("%s",message);
        }
    }
    free(message);
}
`
```

Comment: `"hey"` is of type `const char[4]`; attempts to write to memory occupied by a string literal exhibit undefined behavior. Many compilers in fact store string literals in a segment of memory marked read-only.

Comment: An array is not a pointer and vice-versa, but it is converted to one to its first element on certain usages. Read a good C book to learn this vital concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Igor Tandetnik says precisely in his comment, attempts to write to memory occupied by a string literal exhibit undefined behavior.

Thus the line:

```
char*message="hey";
```

is the problem. The string "hey" is likely in read-only memory but might not be - the compiler could theoretically allocate 4 bytes on the stack and point message to it. In which case you could write 4 bytes before smashing your stack.

It's best not to guess and use:

```
const char*message="hey";
```

If you need to write to message, either use an array like you already have done; pointers and arrays are interchangeable (but not identical, see the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/)), or allocate an appropriate amount of memory:

```
char *message;

message = malloc(100);    /* 100 bytes allocated */
if (message == NULL)      /* The allocation failed */
   ...error...

/* Write to message */

free(message);     /* Free the 100 bytes */
```

Comment: could not be on the stack (lifetime!), though could be in writable memory. And might be shared---

Comment: I thought I remembered some ancient compilers deciding that a non static local pointer to a literal could be implemented as such. Maybe I'm wrong - it's at least 20 years back...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the differences between char-pointer and array of char:
When declaring the following code, as Igor Tandetnik said, you are allocating a const char[4] = { 'k', 'e', 'y', '\0' }; in a read-only area of your software.

```
char*message="hey";
```

When declaring the following code, you are allocating a char[10] in the stack (writable) and initialize it with the array { 'k', 'e', 'y', '\0' ... '\0' };

```
char message[10] ="hey" ;
```

Be carefull, the second use will work while the length of the user-entry stays smaller than 9 characters.